# Clarification of which theorem or proposition is used to proof continuity on a segment.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, proof-explanation

In one of my tutorial exercises I had the following question:

> Let $f:[a,b] \to \mathbf{R}$ be an integrable function. Show that $F: x\in [a,b] \mapsto \int_a^xf(y)dy$ is continuous.

The given proof is:

> By Chalse's identity, $$|F(x_0+h) - F(x_0)| = \left| \int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}f(y)dy \right| \leq \int_{x_0}^{x_0+h}|f(y)|dy \leq h\sup_{[a,b]}f  \xrightarrow[h \to 0]{} 0 $$

Since I am not proficient with the method of proving continuity of functions on an arbitrary interval, I am not able to identity why the above result implies continuity.

Comment: Do you know the definition of the assertion "$F(x)$ is continuous at $x=x_0$"?